# libunrar RARReadHeader always return ERAR_BAD_DATA

Tags: c++, c, rar, unrar

guys, I'm recently working on the `libunrar`, but got error when I use `RAR_OM_LIST` option, I can get the first item in the rar file printed, but got `ERAR_BAD_DATA` afterwards. here's the code:

```
struct RAROpenArchiveData openArcData = {
        .ArcName = (char *)"/Users/oxnz/Developer/Nanook/unrar/x.rar",
        .OpenMode = RAR_OM_LIST,
    };
    HANDLE hArcData = RAROpenArchive(&openArcData);
    if (openArcData.OpenResult == ERAR_SUCCESS) {
        struct RARHeaderDataEx headerDataEx;
        int ret;
        while (ERAR_SUCCESS == (ret = RARReadHeaderEx(hArcData, &headerDataEx))) {
            printf("file: [%s]\n", headerDataEx.FileName);
        }
        switch (ret) {
            case ERAR_BAD_DATA:
                printf("bad data\n");
                break;
            case ERAR_END_ARCHIVE:
                printf("END OF ARCHIVE\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("unknown error: %d", ret);
                break;
        }
        RARCloseArchive(hArcData);
    }
```

any information would be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After each call to `RARReadHeaderEx` you need to call `RARProcessFile`, even if it's only to skip over the data. E.g.

```
while (ERAR_SUCCESS == (ret = RARReadHeaderEx(hArcData, &headerDataEx)))
{
    printf("file: [%s]\n", headerDataEx.FileName);
    if (ERAR_SUCCESS != (ret = RARProcessFile(hArcData, RAR_SKIP, NULL, NULL)))
        break;
}
```

Comment: But this doesn't resolve the issue in any way. You've just skipped error handling.

Comment: @EugeneSue Not sure I follow.